# Where's my `head` at?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

When browsing on GameFAQS, one of my Greasemonkey scripts broke with Firefox version 56.  It's a very simple one:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        MakeSignaturesBlack
// @namespace   tarelessar
// @description Makes the signatures black again
// @include     https://*.gamefaqs.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
//Makes signatures black I guess

var sheet = document.createElement ('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".signature {color: inherit !important}";
document.head.appendChild(sheet);
```

This script was written to change the gray signature bar on the site to black and has worked all the way up to version 54 of Firefox.  After that, it stopped working on version 56.

When I troubleshot it, I found that **the `document.head` was null.**  From doing a little research, I found that `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];` should be used and tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        MakeSignaturesBlack
// @namespace   tarelessar
// @description Makes the signatures black again
// @include     https://*.gamefaqs.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
//Makes signatures black I guess

var sheet = document.createElement ('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".signature {color: inherit !important}";
document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];.appendChild(sheet);
```

...it made no change to the signature color.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I change the "head" element so that it changes the signature color?

Comment: You need to wait for the DOM to be loaded, before you can access it. `document.head` is fine. Either use `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){`…`});` or remove `@run-at document-start`.

Comment: You have written `a || b;.c()` when you meant `(a || b).c()`.

Comment: document.head is NOT fine.  When I opened the error console, is said that document.head is null.  Therefore, I need something else for "head". Also, bare with me.  I know next to nothing about coding.  Just a little basic stuff.  The easiest that could be done for a newb like me is just a repost of the script with the changes.

Comment: @Brock Adams how do I upvote an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@run-at document-start` mode, Greasemonkey scripts can indeed fire before the `document.head` is available.  In such cases, fall back to `documentElement`.

Code like this is best:

```
let D           = document;
let sheet       = D.createElement ('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".signature {color: inherit !important}";
let targ        = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
targ.appendChild (sheet);
```

However, if you are just changing the appearance by injecting CSS, you would be smarter to use [the Stylish extension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stylish/info). It's easier and performs better for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The new script works excellent.  For some reason, the versions of Firefox that are above 54 don't support document.head anymore.  At least it didn't when I launched the error console to check for script issues.  The document.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] seems to be the better replacement.  Anyway, the grayed out script is now black so it works.  Thanks everyone!